# How much UVA and UVB is blocked by shadow or being indoors?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, atmospheric-science, estimation

I could not find a clear answer online so I though to try this forum instead.

I did find answers on how different types of glass can block different degrees of UVA and UVB. But I was wondering, if I am sitting inside and the sun is not exposed directly onto me while being indoors, to how much % UVA and UVB am I still exposed? I was also wondering the same about if I am outside but standing in the shadow. Also, how much UVA and UVB are blocked by sheer curtains?

I have little knowledge about physics and I do not know if I formulated all of this correctly. I hope it is understandable.

Comment: Re, "blocked by shadow." Whatever is casting the shadow usually blocks 100% of every wavelength of light. If you are outdoors, standing in shadow, and there's enough light for you to see your hand in front of your face, it's because you are illuminated by light reflected from things all around that are _not_ in the shadow and, by scattered light from the blue sky and/or clouds. The amount of UV in the shadow will depend in part on what wavelengths are reflected by the "things." White sand? Green grass? Brick walls? Tree trunks? etc. and, in part on how much sky you can see and how many clouds.

Comment: Yes exactly, so I discovered this in the meantime already. So now the question that I would have is what particular objects reflect how much UV light. I understood that bricks and concrete reflect little while water and snow can reflect a lot? Is there some kind of heuristic that I can apply to estimate how much an object will reflect how much UV? Basically I would want to know if I walk through the city or forest or whatever, what path would be the best to walk such that I minimise UV exposure.